Error: Invalid HTTP method/URL pair when using getDownloadURL on a file produced by the Transcoder API
I am using the Transcoder API to format videos into a 1:1 aspect ratio. The source video file is stored in a Firebase Storage bucket. When the transcoded file is generated, it does not have an access token, so to view the file, I can manually create the access token using the console. This way I am able to get a URL that I use to access the transcoded file.
I want generate a download URL in my cloud function for the the ChromeCast.mp4 file in picture below:

When I run the following code, I get "Error: Invalid HTTP method/URL pair." in my log with the following code:
            // Create a download URL for transcoded file

            const { getStorage, getDownloadURL } = require('firebase-admin/storage');

            var newBucket = `*MY-BUCKET-NAME*.appspot.com/transcoder/`
            var newName = `ChromeCast.mp4`;

            console.log(`newBucket: ${newBucket}`);
            console.log(`newName: ${newName}`);

            const fileRef = getStorage().bucket(`${newBucket}`).file(`${newName}`);
            const downloadURL= await getDownloadURL(fileRef);

            console.log(downloadURL);

The line "const downloadURL= await getDownloadURL(fileRef)" is generating the error. I have tried the following variations of the bucket name:
var newBucket = `*MY-BUCKET-NAME*.appspot.com/transcoder%2F`

var newBucket = `*MY-BUCKET-NAME*.appspot.com/transcoder`

But I still get the same error.
I have also tried removing the following code variation, but get  'Error: Not Found'
        var newBucket = `*MY-BUCKET-NAME*.appspot.com`
        var newName = `/transcoder/ChromeCast.mp4`;

        const fileRef = getStorage().bucket(`${newBucket}`).file(`${newName}`);

        const downloadURL= await getDownloadURL(fileRef);

I am using a hardcoded bucket for testing purposes.
I want to generate a download URL so I can update a document with the new URL, replacing the URL to original video file

Which line of code causes the error?  Please edit the question to show what you've done to debug this so far.

Also are you sure you have the correct value for newBucket?  That should just be the unique name of the bucket.  It looks like you have something else in that string that isn't part of the bucket name (what is "transcoder"?).

I have update the question showing what I have tried.

I tried the answer below. I does not work, I am getting a 'Error: Not Found'

The string "transcoder" is not part of your bucket name.  It's part of the path to the object you're trying to work with.  Your variables should look like this:
var newBucket = `*MY-BUCKET-NAME*.appspot.com`
var newName = `transcoder/ChromeCast.mp4`;


The above answer is almost right. It sent me in the right direction. When defining the file name, remove the leading '/' in front of transcoder. It should look like this var newName = transcoder/ChromeCast.mp4;
